# .NET - Does Return prevent objects disposing

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, return

Given the following code:

```
  Function GetSomething() As Integer
    Using dbConn As New SqlConnection("Connection_String")
      dbConn.Open()
      Using dbCmd As New SqlCommand(" SELECT SOMETHING ....", dbConn)
        Return Integer.Parse(dbCmd.ExecuteScalar())
      End Using
      dbConn.Close()
    End Using
  End Function
```

Will the Return prevent execution of the remainder of the function block i.e. the closing of the database connection and the implied Dispose() called when the Using block finishes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, a [`Using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) is equivalent to a [`Try`/`Finally`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) statement - so the disposal is executed as execution leaves the block, whether that's by reaching the end of the block, returning normally, or via an exception.

You don't need the explicit `Close` call though, as you're disposing of the connection anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'm glad that's the case as it seems eminently sensible.